# Pinging using a variable

Tags: batch-file, ping, environment-variables

I'm trying to create a batch file that will ping a variable that is determined by the users input

e.g. "Enter PC Name:" pc name =123

Then it pings 123.domain.com

```
@echo off
set /p UserInputPath = Enter chosen PC: 

ping %UserInputPath%

ping MyServerName

PAUSE
```

`Ping MyServerName` works fine

But `ping %UserInputPath%` doesn't and just brings up the "Help" Menu for Ping in CMD

Any help would be appreciated
::::EDIT:::

```
ping %UserInputPath% -n 5
```

Returns this error: `IP address must be specified.`

Can you not a ping a hostname? (AS that is what i'm trying to do)

EDIT 2::

This is my latest:

```
@echo off
set /p UserInputPath = "Enter chosen PC: " 
PAUSE 

ping %UserInputPath%.store.domain.company.com

ping MyServerName

PAUSE
```

Comment: Looks like you got the order of arguments wrong.

Comment: This is my latest:

@echo off
set /p UserInputPath = "Enter chosen PC: " 

PAUSE 

ping %UserInputPath%.store.domain.company.com

ping MyServerName

PAUSE  10.88.132.72

Comment: Please use [proper formatting](http://superuser.com/editing-help) when writing questions or answers.

Comment: @DanielB sorry for that

Comment: When you use `ping %UserInputPath%.store.domain.company.com`, what precisely is the user input? If you put an `echo %UserInputPath%.store.domain.company.com` what does it print?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set /p UserInputPath = Enter chosen PC: 
                    ^ This space is included in the name of the variable
```

So you end with a variable named `%UserInputPath %`

Better use

```
set /p "UserInputPath=Enter Chosen PC: "
ping "%UserInputPath%.store.domain.company.com"
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see that.... you absolute life saver!!!

Answer (score 1):

Following script works, at least for me on Win7.

```
@echo off
set /p name="Enter name:"
ping %name%.google.com
```

We first ask user to enter name, then store it in `name` variable, and pass it to `ping` (see `%name%`) adding `google.com` (just as example!).

Comment: I tried that and get this error: Ping request could not find host .store.domain.company.com Please check the name and try again.

Comment: Alex, ensure your domain name could be pinged directly from command line.

Comment: @user996142 - I can ping the machine via command line with no issues

Comment: Try simply ``ping %name%`` and enter full domain name

Comment: that doesn't work unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fancy bash script for you. Hacked it out earlier today for the original question before realizing it was for Windows. Considered converting it to a batch file for you but it looked painful. Reminded me of writing startup scripts in college.

You need to use Powershell or spin up a *nix host somewhere. Powershell v3 is really nice. You could convert this into powershell rather easily actually.

There'll be a few down votes for this but who cares. Someone'll find this script useful. At the very least you can plunder the logic and regex.

Tested in Debian.

```
#!/bin/bash
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
# superuserping.sh # Can be changed :P
# /usr/bin/superuserping.sh # Put it wherever you like...
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
# Usage:           ./superuserping.sh [fqdn|shortname|ip]
#                  If no argument is passed it will ask for one
# Author:          Alex Atkinson
# Author Date:     May 25, 2015

# ------------------------------------------------------------------
# VARIABLES
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
domain="domain.com"
rxshort='^[A-Za-z0-9]{1,63}$'
rxfqdn='^([A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,6}$'
rxip='^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$'

# ------------------------------------------------------------------
# Check for argument. Get one if none found.
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
if [ -z $1 ]; then
    echo -n "Enter the hostname or IP to ping and press [ENTER]: "
    read host
else
    host=$1
fi

# ------------------------------------------------------------------
# ARGUMENT VALIDATION
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
checkshort=$([[ $host =~ $rxshort ]])
checkshort=$?
checkfqdn=$([[ $host =~ $rxfqdn ]])
checkfqdn=$?
checkip=$([[ $host =~ $rxip ]])
checkip=$?

# ------------------------------------------------------------------
# FUNCTIONS
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
function check_userinput()
{
    # Validate userinput against shortname, fqdn, and IP regex. If shortname then add domain.
    if [[ $checkshort == '0' ]] || [[ $checkfqdn == "0" ]] || [[ $checkip == "0" ]] ; then
        if [[ $checkip == 1 ]]; then
            if [[ $host != *$domain ]]; then
                host=$host.$domain
            fi
        fi
    else
        echo -e "\e[00;31mERROR\e[00m: ERROR:" $host "does not appear to be a valid shortname, fqdn, or IP."
        exit 1
    fi
}

function resolve_host()
{
    # Check for DNS host resolution.
    dnscheck=$(host $host)
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo -e "\n"$dnscheck "\n"
    else
        echo -e "\n\e[00;31mERROR\e[00m: DNS was unable to resolve the provided hostname or IP:" $host".\n"
        echo -n "Press [ENTER] key to continue with ping, or [Q] to quit..."
        read -n 1 -s key
        if [[ $key = q ]] || [[ $key = Q ]]; then
            echo -e "\nExiting...\n"
            exit 1

        fi
    fi
}

# ------------------------------------------------------------------
# MAIN OPERATIONS
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
check_userinput
resolve_host
ping $host
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you did fall into the *delayed expansion trap* and your code snippet is enclosed between `(` and `)`. When you use a variable changed inside such a block then you need to [enable delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)...

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set "UserInputPath=AnotherServer"

(
    set "UserInputPath=MyServerName"
    rem set /p "UserInputPath = Enter chosen PC: "

    echo 1st percent-expansion %UserInputPath%
    echo 1st delayedexpansion  !UserInputPath!
)
echo(
echo 2nd percent-expansion %UserInputPath%
echo 2nd delayedexpansion  !UserInputPath!
```

Output:

```
1st percent-expansion AnotherServer
1st delayedexpansion  MyServerName

2nd percent-expansion MyServerName
2nd delayedexpansion  MyServerName
```